# Sort function doesn't work on object

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort an object in JS, but the sort function doesn't seem to work for my object.

I want to sort my array by frequency, descending.

`["B", "A", "C", "C", "A"]` will result in `[C: 2, A: 2, B: 1]`

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/64q43/

```
var arr = ["B", "A", "C", "C", "A"];
var arrFrequency = [];

arr.forEach(function(value) {
  arrFrequency[value] = 0;
});

console.log(arrFrequency);
// [B: 0, A: 0, C: 0] 

arr.filter(function(value) {
  if (arrFrequency.hasOwnProperty(value)) arrFrequency[value]++;
});

console.log(arrFrequency);
// [B: 1, A: 2, C: 2]
```

Comment: [You cannot sort objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-javascript-object-by-property-value). You can only sort numerically-indexed arrays. [Do not use an array for `arrFrequency`](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Where are you sorting?

Comment: `[C: 2, A: 2, B: 1]` is not valid in JavaScript.  It doesn't have associative arrays.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: I think it is what the console logs when you've put string keys on an array (which you of course should not).

Comment: @Bergi: He's just added properties to the variable, so that's what's being printed.  It's still an array with zero length.  I guess...

Comment: You have an array, and you are adding custom properties to it (you can add custom properties to almost everything).  When you sort an array, it only looks at the array elements (numbered keys).  JavaScript does *not* have associative arrays.

Comment: Uh? I don't see you sorting anything. Where are you calling `.sort`? You know that `.filter` doesn't sort, right? You are not even using the function correctly, you should use `.forEach` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects don't have any defined order. However, you can first create a an object like this:

```
var arr = ["B", "A", "C", "C", "A"];
var freq = {};
arr.forEach(function(value) {
    freq[value] = (freq[value] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(freq); // {B: 1, A: 2, C: 2}
```

And then map the keys of this object to an array:

```
var arrFrequency = [];
for(var k in freq) {
    arrFrequency.push({ key: k, count: freq[k] });
};
console.log(arrFrequency); // [{"key":"B","count":1},{"key":"A","count":2},{"key":"C","count":2}]
```

And now sort it like this:

```
arrFrequency.sort(function(x, y) {
    return y.count - x.count;
});
console.log(arrFrequency); // [{"key":"A","count":2},{"key":"C","count":2},{"key":"B","count":1}]
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/8yHJ4/)

Answer (score 0):

My this form of sorting function helps you:

```
 // sort objects according to their key-names (a,b,c):

 function sortObjArray(array){
    for(var k=1; k < array.length; k++){
      for(var i=k; i > 0; i--){
        var formerLetter = Object.keys(array[i-1]);
        var currLetter = Object.keys(array[i]);
        if( currLetter < formerLetter ){
          [x,y] = [array[i],array[i-1]];
          [array[i],array[i-1]] = [y,x];
        }
      }
    }
    return array;
 }

 var array = [{ b: 4},{ c: 1},{ a: 3}];
 sortObjArray(array);//[Object { a=3}, Object { b=4}, Object { c=1}]


 // or in descending order, according to their occurrence

 function sortObjArray2(array){
    for(var k=1; k < array.length; k++){
       for(var i=k; i > 0; i--){
          var formerLetter = Object.keys(array[i-1])[0];
          var currLetter = Object.keys(array[i])[0];

          var formerValue = array[i-1][formerLetter]; 
          var currValue = array[i][currLetter];

          if( currValue> formerValue ){
            [x,y] = [array[i],array[i-1]];
            [array[i],array[i-1]] = [y,x];
          }
       }
     }
     return array;
  }

  var array = [{ b: 4},{ c: 1},{ a: 3}];
  sortObjArray2(array);//[Object { b=4}, Object { a=3}, Object { c=1}]
```